# SharePoint online specify who can change issue status in a issue tracking list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions, issue-tracking

I have an issue tracking list set up on SharePoint Online with the 3 state workflow running for email notifications. Is it possible to configure the list/set up a workflow so that, dynamically, only the person who is assigned the issue can change the item status from active to resolved and only the person who created the issue can change item status from resolved to closed. I have looked at the approval workflow but it doesn't fit requirements (issues need to be visible to all from the point on creation) and item level permissions seem to refer to visible to users and not controlling who can take what action on list items. I am fairly new to SharePoint so any help/advice would be great! Thanks.